Are there korean words that contain the letter ㄹ that are not transliterations of European words?
Are there korean words that contain the letter ㄹ that are not transliterations of European words?
Many transliterations of European words use the letter ㄹ.



KoreanOrthography
Non-StandardEnglishOrthographyMixed With Korean
StandardEnglishOrthography




레스토랑
LAY-SOO-TOO-RAWNTLe Surant
Restaurant


리더를
LEE-DUHL-RAWre-doo-rawleader rule
Leader


재활용
TAY-WA-REEOONT-EH-EE-W-AW-R-EE-OO-N
Recycling


롤링
LO-LEE-NGROLEENG
rolling



Does there exists a word x such that x is a word in the Korean language and word x is more than 300 years old, such that old word x uses the letter  ㄹ?

The answer to your question is obviously yes, as mach mentioned basic words like  둘 exist.
The answer to the question I assume you intended to ask: Are there words with word initial ㄹ which are not recent borrowings from non-east-Asian languages?
The answer is yes, but not many in standard Korean. 라면 for example, although this is borrowed in Hanja form from Chinese via Japanese, but in the twentieth century.
The reason for this is that almost all initial ㄹ shifted to ㄴ or ㅇ in Seoul dialect prior to standardisation. Notably this shift is not present in the North Korean standard, and the inital r/l can be found in the Japanese and Chinese counterparts of many Korean words.
Edit to add: 재활용 is a sino-Korean word, no transliteration from English involved.

There certainly are, e.g. 둘 (dul) ‘two’, or 그루 (geuru) ‘(tree) stump, (plant) stock’.
Native Korean words do not start with ㄹ, but many Sino-Korean words do. In South Korean, the initial ㄹ is not written before /i/ or /j/, or written as ㄴ /n/ before other sounds according to the initial sound rule. The ㄹ reappears, however, in compounds. In North Korean, the ㄹ is always written (cf. 두음법칙 - When did North and South diverge in pronunciation of initial ㄹ?).
This is why the common Korean surname Lee is really written 이 (I) in South Korea, but 리 (Ri) in North Korea.
Examples of reappearing ㄹ in compounds include 이 (i 理, North Korean 리 ri) ‘reason, logic’ vs. 요리 (yori 料理) ‘cooking, cuisine’, or 낙 (nak 樂, North Korean 락 rak) ‘joy’ vs. 오락 (orak 娛樂) ‘entertainment, amusement’.
